# how to remove the type attribute in property in wso2 esb developer studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When i create a property element in WSO2 ESB it allows me to create without the "type" attribute being mentioned like

However while using the WSO2 developer studio to generate the property in one of the sequences it kind of mandates the 'type' attribute to be present . Is there an option to override it.

i tried removing the attribute in source view and tried saving it . But it overrides and invoked the attribute during save.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute 'type' is mandatory in developer studio. If you are creating the sequence through the design view and you didn't define type it will consider as String by default.

If you are creating the sequence through the source view and you didn't define type or remove the type and save it will consider as OMElement by default.